# Зачем этот алгоритм и что он делает?

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Есть кусок кода, я не понимаю, зачем он и как работает. По идее функция `getComponentTypeID()` возвращает какой-то ID (зависящий от количества вызовов) на 1 больше чем прошлый. Но вот что делает последняя функция я не понимаю. Зачем нам template если мы его нигде не используем, а используем только ComponentID. И почему мы возвращаем `typeID()` <- со скобочками, если это вроде как переменная?
Наверняка я просто плохо знаю все эти темплы

```
using ComponentID = std::size_t;

inline ComponentID getComponentTypeID() {
    static ComponentID lastID = 0;
    return lastID++;
}

template<typename T> inline ComponentID getComponentTypeID() noexcept {
    static ComponentID typeID = getComponentTypeID();
    return typeID();
}
```

Comment: Шаблон явно нужен чтобы генерировать разные идентификаторы для разных типов. "почему мы возвращаем typeID() <- со скобочками" - это ошибка

Comment: то есть для каждого типа данных они будут генерироваться с нуля?

Comment: Нет, для каждого типа данных они будут разные, так как каждый новый вызов `getComponentTypeID` (инициализирующий переменную `typeID` только один раз) будет возвращать новый результат

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Идентификация разных типов. При сравнении одного типа с другим выдаётся другое число. Типы имеют иногда свой синоним с помощью `typedef`, или `define`. Иногда сравнение по размеру не помогает. Это аналог системной функции `typeid`.

```
// $ g++ -Wall tempstat.cpp
# include <iostream>

using ComponentID = std::size_t;

inline ComponentID getComponentTypeID() {
    static ComponentID lastID = 0;
    return lastID++;
}

template<typename T> inline ComponentID getComponentTypeID() noexcept {
    static ComponentID typeID = getComponentTypeID();
    return typeID;
}

typedef unsigned  char  bytec ;
typedef uint8_t byte8 ;

int main(){
  std::cout<<"int = "<<getComponentTypeID<int>()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"char = "<<getComponentTypeID<char>()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"unsigned char = "<<getComponentTypeID<unsigned char>()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"bytec = "<<getComponentTypeID<bytec>()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"byte8 = "<<getComponentTypeID<byte8>()<<std::endl;

  std::cout<<"int = "<<typeid(int).name()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"char = "<<typeid(char).name()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"unsigned char = "<<typeid(unsigned char).name()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"bytec = "<<typeid(bytec).name()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"byte8 = "<<typeid(byte8).name()<<std::endl;
}
```

Результат:

```
int = 0
char = 1
unsigned char = 2
bytec = 2
byte8 = 2

int = i
char = c
unsigned char = h
bytec = h
byte8 = h
```

Результат показывает, что типы `char` и `unsigned char` - разные. А `uint8_t` - это синоним типа `unsigned char`.